# Switch Case with String Arrays using

Tags: java, arrays, string, switch-statement

```
String[] months={"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L"};
int valueMonth;

Scanner yasin=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please input your month number: ");
valueMonth=(yasin.nextInt());


switch (valueMonth) {
    case 1: months[valueMonth];
        break;       

}
```

I'm making something wrong with switch cases and string arrays. How can i solve this without doing it with `if-else`.. Thank you..
ps: if i did syntax error on website, its not that.

I solved this exercise like that;

```
String[] months={"a", "b" ,"c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"}; 
int valueMonth; 
Scanner tara=new Scanner(System.in); 
System.out.println("Input Number : "); 
valueMonth=tara.nextInt(); 
if(valueMonth>0 && valueMonth<=12){
    System.out.println(months[ valueMonth- 1]);
}else{
    System.err.println("ERROR"); 
}
```

AND i wanted to make more exercise and tried to do it with `Switch-Case` statement. But it's not working. Maybe I am missing something or its just not working at all – Yasin Atagün 7 mins ago

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? what error do you get?

case 1, means that it will execute everything between the colon and the break; if months == 1. But it looks like months is an array... Maybe you meant to put switch(valueMonths). That's an int, like 1.

Comment: My exercise is getting value from user, and by this input month on screen. Like if he said 4, program will input April on screen. I can do it only with switch case statement. But im on arrays topic on java. and teacher did it with if else. I easly did that. But now im tryign to do it with switch case if its possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this for Switch Statement.

```
String[] months = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Now","Dec"};
int monthNumber;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please input your month number: ");
monthNumber = (scan.nextInt());

    switch(monthNumber) {
        case 1 :
            System.out.println(months[0]); 
            break;
        case 2 :
            System.out.println(months[1]); 
            break;
        case 3 :
            System.out.println(months[2]); 
            break;
        case 4 :
            System.out.println(months[3]); 
            break;
        case 5 :
            System.out.println(months[4]); 
            break;
        case 6 :
            System.out.println(months[5]); 
            break;
        case 7 :
            System.out.println(months[6]); 
            break;
        case 8 :
            System.out.println(months[7]); 
            break;                
        case 9 :
            System.out.println(months[8]); 
            break;
        case 10 :
            System.out.println(months[9]); 
            break;
        case 11 :
            System.out.println(months[10]); 
            break;
        case 12 :
            System.out.println(months[11]); 
            break;            
         default :
            System.out.println("Invalid Month Number");
      }
```

OR you can simply do this

```
      if(monthNumber>0 && monthNumber<=12){
        System.out.println(months[monthNumber-1]); 
      }else{
          System.out.println("Invalid Month Number");
      }
```

Comment: Usama, i know its a rule that we shoould not thank here. But thank you. Just one more question. Cant i do it without writing months[10] and write like months[monthnumber-1] or sometin like that?

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle Java tutorial on switch statement covers this exact scenario, I believe.

Take a look - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Java per se, but I know the switch statement in other languages. Hopefully this pseudo-code structure will help you see what you're doing wrong.

```
switch ( WHAT_WILL_HAVE_THE_VALUE_IN_CASE ) {
  case POTENTIAL_VALUE_A: 
     ... lines of code that will execute if WHAT_WILL_HAVE_THE_VALUE_IN_CASE == POTENTIAL_VALUE_A ...
    break;
  case POTENTIAL_VALUE_B: 
     ... same thing as before, for VALUE_B ...
    break;
  default: 
     ... what will happen if none of the above applied ...
    break;
}
```

In your case, WHAT_WILL_HAVE_THE_VALUE_IN_CASE should be a variable containing the number of the month. Each case should have a number (1-12) as it's POTENTIAL_VALUE. Inside the code for each case, you'll have something that will print the name of the month "April", for example, to the screen/console/file you're using.

Good luck with your assignment!

Comment: Ty for helping, im trying to do more exercices on even same questions. I hope it will make my knowledge better on this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot supply an array as a switch-case parameter (like `switch (months)`).

It's not much clear what your intention is, please fill in with more details about what are you trying to accomplish.

From what it seems, simply calling `months[valueMonth-1]` will return the proper string.
To ensure against invalid inputs you can use a `try-catch` statement, like this:

```
try {
    theMonth = months[valueMonth-1];
} catch (ArrayOutOfBoundsException ex) {
    System.out.println("Invalid number!");
}
```

Comment: i think you meant `valueMonth-1`

Comment: I rewrite the question.

Answer (score 0):

it might be irrelevant but your trying to make the switch case **SHORTER** I assume, this works on .Net6 (Not sure on previous version.)

```
    String[] months = {"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Now","Dec"};
    int monthNumber;    
    int valueMonth;
    
    Scanner yasin=new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("Please input your month number: ");
    valueMonth=(yasin.nextInt());
    
    
    switch (valueMonth) {
        case "Jan" or "Feb" or "Mar" or "Apr" or "May" or "Jun":
            break;
        case "Jul" or "Aug" or "Sep" or "Oct" or "Now" or "Dec":
            break;
    }
```